# Changing visible months in a Calendar Swift

Tags: swift

I am working with `Calendar` and I am able to get some things in that for this current year, I have Jan, feb, march, April, may, June, July ... up to December. But now since we are in May, I do not want to see June, July, Aug .... up to December. Rather I want to see `Jan, feb, march, April, may` and be able to scroll backwards to probably `... Nov, 2020`, `Dec, 2020` With the current implementation of Calendar I do not understand how to pick this out.

This is what I use to get my Months currently `private let months = Calendar.current.shortMonthSymbols.map { $0.uppercased() }`

Which results into `Jan, feb, march, April, may, June, July ... up to December` how can I change this behaviour to reflect what I want?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use an enumerator on the array and then use `prefix(while:)` to get all months up to the current one.

```
let thisMonth = Calendar.current component(.month, from: Date())
let currentYearMonths = Calendar.current.shortMonthSymbols.enumerated()
    .prefix(while: { $0.offset < thisMonth })
    .filter { $0.offset < thisMonth }
    .map(\.element.localizedUppercase)
```

For the previous year part, calculate last year and then simply join the year to the elements of `.shortMonthSymbols` using `map`

```
let aYearAgo = Calendar.current.date(byAdding: .year, value: -1, to: Date())!
let lastYear = Calendar.current.component(.year, from: aYearAgo)

let lastYearMonths = Calendar.current.shortMonthSymbols.map { "\($0.localizedUppercase), \(lastYear)"}
```

Comment: Thanks for the response, is there a way of adding maybe 2020 and 2019 months to the current.months? but now months from 2020 would have `Jan, 2020` `Feb, 2020` and 2019 would be `Jan, 2019` `Feb, 2019`

Comment: That is the actual question. Displaying other months with years alongside moths in a year up to the current month.

Comment: I was thinking more of a possibility of having an array of years I wanted. like [2019, 2020]

Comment: Cleaned up the answer by creating separate arrays since that is how I wrote the code originally